# Spring component scanning : can we use @componentscan and <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.*" /> in same project?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have configured component scan in dispatcher servlet
**code:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.web.rest"
        annotation-config="true" scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
<annotation-driven />
```

and this code is scanning "com.web.rest" package,
now I have to scan one more package using @ComponentScan annotation,

**Example:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.web.utils"})
@Component
public class FileUtil {
}
```

But @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.web.utils"}) is not working for me, it is not scanning "com.web.utils" package

can we use annotation driven and xml configuration component scan in same project??

Answer (score 0):

You can combine annotation driven configuration file and xml based configuration file together. If you are using a Java @Configuration file, you can simultaneously load in an XML configuration file simply by adding an @ImportResource annotation. The following annotation loads in a Spring XML configuration file named `spring-servlet.xml` into the annotation based Spring ApplicationContext object:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-servlet.xml")
class JConfig { }
```

Make sure that spring-servlet.xml is in your application classpath. For further details refer to http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Combining-Annotation-and-XML-Configurations-in-your-Spring-3-Applications.

Then modify the dispatcher servlet configuration in your web.xml as follows:

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>org.rest.spring.rest</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

You only have to change or add the two `init-param` tags there and the rest will be same as before. Give the param-value of `contextConfigLocation` as the package under which your annotation based config java file resides. And from that annotation based config file import the xml based config file as shown above. Refer to http://www.baeldung.com/bootstraping-a-web-application-with-spring-and-java-based-configuration. Let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Annotation** driven and **XML** configuration component scan in same project. But if you use both, then **XML** configuration overrides **Annotation** driven configuration like it does here for component scan. So we should avoid the mix and if inevitable, we should mix less. Otherwise result is unpredictable sometimes. Below is excerpt from Java documentation(See the 3rd point).

> The following annotation and deployment descriptor combinations are
>   supported:
>
> 1. Java EE applications or modules can be packaged with full Java EE 6
>      compliant standard and runtime deployment descriptors. If the standard
>      deployment descriptors have specified the metadata-complete attribute,
>      annotations in the module are ignored.
> 2. Java EE applications or modules can be fully annotated with metadata
>      defined by the listed specifications. Annotation eliminates the need
>      for Java EE standard deployment descriptors. In most cases, the
>      GlassFish Server deployment descriptors are also not needed.
> 3. Java EE applications or modules can be partially annotated with some
>      deployment information in standard deployment descriptors. In case of
>      conflicts, deployment descriptor values supersede the annotated
>      metadata, and a warning message is logged.

So to solve your problem here, you can add another component scan in your XML configuration file as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.web.utils"
        annotation-config="true" scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
```

and remove the following from your **FileUtil** class.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.web.utils"})
```